# Batch file wait of varying length driven off when a directory becomes empty

Tags: batch-file, wait

We are building an automate export\import between systems.  We are good except for devising a wait of undefined/varying period keyed off of when a directory become empty.

We export files from one system.  Import the files into another system.  Depending on the number of files; the duration of the import will vary notably.

We need to wait for the import staging directory to become empty so we can test for item counts in 2 results directories (import successes and import failures).  Unfortunately the import mechanism is a Windows service so we can’t call it  from the batch.

The best idea we’ve come up with is doing a looped check of whether or not there were files in the import staging directory.  Basically, keep looping through a wait of say 30 seconds until such time as a directory is empty.  (If directory contains >1 objects, wait 30 seconds, else continue with batch.

Has anyone scripted a check\wait like this before?

Answer (score 3):

You can use PING to introduce a delay (works on all Windows platforms)

You can use DIR /B /A-D to test if there are files. The commands after `&&` only execute if DIR was successful (files were found).

```
@echo off
setlocal
set delay=30
set folder=myFolder

set /a delay+=1
:loop
>nul 2>nul dir /b /a-d * && (
  >nul ping -n %delay% ::1
  goto :loop
)
echo %folder% is now empty
```

Comment: +1 but won't `::1` only work if you have IPv6 installed? Which I think XP doesn't. Maybe use `127.0.0.1` to be sure it works on all OS's.